# How to plot data from csv using Dash Plotly and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plotly-dash

In an excel spreadsheet with four sheets (this is an A/B test, Sheet 1 is a_group_flights, Sheet 2 is b_group_flights, Sheet 3 is a_group_hotels, Sheet 4 is b_group_hotels), I'm interested in plotting two of the columns "budget_price" and "total_spend" over a time period shown by "budget_datetime" and have those two lines (budget_price and total_spend) overlap to show the difference between what your budget is and how much you're actually spending over time on trips.

This is what the spreadsheet looks like:
https://ibb.co/JHCf12z

I am using Dash Plotly and want to read the excel spreadsheet with Pandas, and then plot the data on a graph.

> xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')

Answer (score 1):

Read the excel instead with

```
xlsx = pd.read_excel('your_excel_file.xls')
```

To make a simple line plot just make

```
df = xlsx
data = [go.Scatter( x=df['X_axis_column'], y=df['first_y_data', 'second_y_data'] )]
```

If your excel has more than one sheet, just make

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('exel_file.xls', 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('exel_file.xls', 'Sheet2')
```

Then you should check [here](https://plot.ly/pandas/) to see which kind of plot you want

Comment: How would you create a basic line chart (two lines, budget_price column, and total_spend column) vs. time (budget_datetime column)?

Comment: Also how would you iterate through each sheet in the excel file with Pandas?

Comment: I'll add the first part as an edit to the answer, not sure about the second part yet, let be find out

Comment: would that simple line plot code be added within app.layout in Dash?

Comment: You need to take a look at this, then https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started